# Create a char array for every string inside a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to implement in java this little project: I want to rename the episodes  of an entire season in a series using a text file that has the names of all the episodes in that season.
To that end I wrote a code that reads the text file and stores every line of text (the name of an episode) as a string array, where every element of the array stores the name of one episode. Also, I wrote a code that takes the **FIRST** element of that array (an array called arrayLines[]) and renames a given file.
This code works like a charm.
What I want to do next is to create a char array for every element in the string array arrLines[].
The pseudo-code i'm thinking to implement is something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<arrLines.length; i++){
    char line_i+1[] = arrLines[i];
}
```

and thus getting many arrays with the names line_1, line_2,..., line_arrLines.length, with the name of every episode stored as a char array.

How can I implement something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a 2-dimensional `char` array:

```
char[][] lines = new char[arrLines.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < arrLines.length; i++) {
    lines[i] = arrLines[i].toCharArray();
}
```

If you have Java 8, you can use Streams:

```
char[][] lines = Arrays.stream(arrLines)
        .map(String::toCharArray)
        .toArray(char[][]::new);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! worked perfectly (both of them)!
what's a Stream? first time I've heard about them.

Comment: @GabrielEdery it's a broad subject; if you want to read up on it, you can start [here](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/), [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String  toCharArra method.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        char[] charArray = strArray[i].toCharArray();
    }
```